# Why is this type inferred incorrectly?

Tags: typescript

```
export type EventCallbackStackType = {
    StringEvent?: Array<(data: string) => void>;
    ArrayEvent?: Array<(data: string[]) => void>;
};

export type EventCallbackKeysType = keyof EventCallbackStackType;

export type EventCallbackType<T extends EventCallbackKeysType> = Exclude<EventCallbackStackType[T], undefined>[number];

export type CallbackType = EventCallbackType<EventCallbackKeysType>

const test = <T extends EventCallbackKeysType>(k: T, v: EventCallbackType<T>) => {
    const stack: EventCallbackStackType = {}
    stack[k] = [v] // Error
}
```

Why is `stack[k]` inferred as:

```
((data: string) => void)[] & ((data: string[]) => void)[]
```

instead of:

```
((data: string) => void)[] | ((data: string[]) => void)[]
```

Comment: The compiler can't deduce the correlation between `k` and `v`, and it's possible for them to be unrelated as `T` can be a union type, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/NaLg2w). If they can be unrelated then the only safe thing to assign is the intersection, not the union, as per [ms/TS#30769](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769). There are approaches to this involving refactoring types (see [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) but that's why it's happening. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?